# Stripping out the junk from imaplib.list() results

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

Here is my code:

```
import imaplib

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("domain@host.com", port=993, timeout=20) as imap:
   imap.login('user', 'pwd')
   status, folders = imap.list()
```

This is what I get from the `imap.list()` call:

```
status : 'OK'
folders :
00 = {bytes: 28} b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Archive'
01 = {bytes: 29} b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Calendar'
02 = {bytes: 28} b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Clutter'
03 = {bytes: 27} b'(\\HasChildren) "/" Contacts'
04 = {bytes: 41} b'(\\HasChildren) "/" "Conversation History"'
05 = {bytes: 41} b'(\\HasChildren \\Trash) "/" "Deleted Items"'
06 = {bytes: 60} b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items/Group - Contact Tracing"'
07 = {bytes: 35} b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Drafts) "/" Drafts'
08 = {bytes: 32} b'(\\Marked \\HasChildren) "/" INBOX'
09 = {bytes: 44} b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX/Untitled Folder"'
```

My goal is to get just the name of the attached mailboxes. How can I do that?

Comment: try https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 3501](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501), the response to the IMAP `LIST` response contains [the following fields](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-7.2.2):

1. Name attributes
2. Hierarchy delimter
3. Mailbox name

The name attributes are contained in parentheses; the remaining two fields are strings (which may be quoted). The [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) function will do most of the work for you, since it understands quoted strings.

Given a response like:

```
>>> folders[5]
b'(\\HasChildren \\Trash) "/" "Deleted Items"'
```

Splitting that with `shlex.split` yields:

```
>>> shlex.split(folders[5].decode())
['(HasChildren', 'Trash)', '/', 'Deleted Items']
```

We're use the `.decode()` method here to convert the byte string into a regular string (assuming the default encoding, which may or may not be correct).

You can see from the above that your mailbox name will always be the last item of the values returned by `shlex.split`. So you can write:

```
import imaplib

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("domain@host.com", port=993, timeout=20) as imap:
   imap.login('user', 'pwd')
   status, folders = imap.list()

   for folder in folders:
       parsed = shlex.split(folder.decode())
       print(parsed[-1])
```

Which will print:

```
Archive
Calendar
Clutter
Contacts
Conversation History
Deleted Items
Deleted Items/Group - Contact Tracing
Drafts
INBOX
INBOX/Untitled Folder
```